# Grails caching - timeToLive not working

Tags: caching, grails, groovy, ehcache

I am having trouble using caching in Grails. Caching is working fine in that the second time I request an object, it gets served from the cache.

However, I am unable to get `timeToLive` to work. I have set it to 15 seconds and I expect the body of `expensiveGetMethod()` to be executed when I call it after more than 15 seconds.

But no matter how long I wait between calls, the object is always being served from the cache.

What am I doing wrong here? **Why is my object never getting evicted from the cache?**

My service class, with the expensive method:

```
class MyObjectService {

   @Cacheable(value='myCache')
   public expensiveGetMethod(String id) {
        println "+++++++++++++++++ This is an expensive method call for $id"
        new MyObject(id: id)
   }
}
```

My domain object:

```
class MyObject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1
    String id
    String name
}
```

My service.
`grails-app\conf\Config.groovy` looks like this:

```
springcache {
    defaults {
        overflowToDisk = false
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy = "LRU"
        eternal = false
        maxElementsInMemory = 10
    }
    caches {
        myCache {
            timeToLive = 15
            timeToIdle = 15
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that you are using springcache plugin? That's not a good choice, since it's no longer maintained and out-dated. You should use cache plugin instead - http://grails.org/plugin/cache

Comment: I'm not sure changing to the cache plugin will be much help. According to its owner, it does not support TTL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14845782/1389219

Comment: Not by itself, but you can use any cache implementation that does.

Comment: Yep, definitely use [Cache Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cache) and [Ehcache Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cache-ehcache) for the TTL stuff. Both of them are supported by Pivotal, so they shouldn't be going away any time soon.